# kitchen backsplash tile grout or caulking

Tags: tile, backsplash

We have tiles at the kitchen backsplash from the top of the countertop (quartz; has a 3" upturn) to the underside of upper cabinets. Should there be grout or caulking at the horizontal joints where it hits the countertop and cabinet underside? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You might push soap or grime into the gap at the bottom of the cabinets when cleaning the tiles, so it's probably a good idea to seal the gap. I didn't do this in my kitchen and I think intelligent life is evolving in there.

I'd use silicone caulking instead of grout at the these locations, because it's more flexible, and I'm convinced that there is always some tiny flexing or movement between the cabinet or the counter top and the wall.

Comment: Perfect timing.... I'm  redoing the seam  between my countertop and backsplash  an was wondering about this. I definitely don't want any intelligent life evolving around here.